# Error in NX Open: ModelCompare function API called UF_MODL_model_compare

Tags: vb.net

I am receiving an error (see picture below) while debugging the `Model Compare` function in both NX 10 & 11 environments.

Can anyone help me to solve this error as I don't understand the meaning of "an RM Object has an unsuitable OM class."

Code:

```
Function MyModelCompare(ByVal iListWindow As ListingWindow, ByRef iPart1 As Part, ByRef iPart2 As Part) As ComparePartMapData

        Try
        Dim intPart1Tag As NXOpen.Tag = iPart1.Tag         'Tag derived from input part1 
            Dim oBody_Eids_Part1 As Tag = CType(vbNull, NXOpen.Tag)
             'Dim oPartTransform1 As Double()
            Dim intPart2Tag As NXOpen.Tag = iPart2.Tag
            Dim oBody_Eids_Part2 As NXOpen.Tag = CType(vbNull, NXOpen.Tag)
             'Dim oPartTransform2 As Double()


           'iListWindow.WriteLine(TypeName(nxMappingData))
            iListWindow.WriteLine("Part1 Tag: " & CStr(intPart1Tag))
            iListWindow.WriteLine("oBody_Eids_Part1: " & CStr(oBody_Eids_Part1))
            iListWindow.WriteLine("intPart2Tag: " & CStr(intPart2Tag))
            iListWindow.WriteLine("oBody_Eids_Part2: " & CStr(oBody_Eids_Part2))



            Dim theUFSession As UFSession = Nothing

            Try
                theUFSession = UFSession.GetUFSession()
                If Not theUFSession Is Nothing Then
                    ilistWindow.WriteLine("Session Tag: " + CStr(theUFSession.Tag.ToString))
                Else
                    iListWindow.WriteLine("Session is nothing!")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
            End Try

            'Initialize nx CompareMapdata

            Dim nxMappingData As ComparePartMapData
            theUFSession.Modl.InitializeCompareData(nxMappingData)

            iListWindow.WriteLine("NX identical parts value = " + CStr(nxMappingData.identical_parts))
            iListWindow.WriteLine(nxMappingData.part1.edges.num_entities.ToString)

            iListWindow.WriteLine("UF Session derived!")
            Dim a_mtx4Identity(15) As Double
            theUFSession.Mtx4.Identity(a_mtx4Identity)


            Dim oModl As UFModl = Nothing
            Try
                oModl = theUFSession.Modl
            Catch ex1 As Exception
                iListWindow.WriteLine("Unable to get Modl object!")
            End Try

            'Try
            '    theUFSession.Modl.FreeCompareData(nxMappingData)
            'Catch ex1 As Exception
            '    Throw New Exception("Error with FreeCompareData3!")
            'End Try

            Dim dblTolerance As Double = 0.001
            Try


                oModl.ModelCompare(intPart1Tag,
                                    oBody_Eids_Part1,
                                    a_mtx4Identity,
                                    intPart2Tag,
                                    oBody_Eids_Part2,
                                    a_mtx4Identity,
                                    True,
                                    CompareAccuracy.CompCoarse,
                                    dblTolerance,
                                    CompareIdenticalfaceRule.CompAlledges,
                                    CompareChangeduniquefaceRule.CompNonidenticalsfChanged,
                                    False,
                                    nxMappingData)

            Catch ex1 As Exception
                Throw New Exception(ex1.message.Tostring)
            End Try

            Return nxMappingData
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Screenshot of error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVjZ0.jpg]

Comment: Is this problem still current?